# Getting the raw body of a request to a SvelteKit endpoint

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, sveltekit

I have an endpoint in my SvelteKit app which handles webhook requests from Stripe. Each request is signed so that it can be verified to come from Stripe.

The code I have to verify the event is from Stripe looks something like this:

```
import Stripe from "stripe";

const WEBHOOK_SECRET = process.env["STRIPE_WH_SECRET"];

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env["STRIPE_SECRET"], {
  apiVersion: "2020-08-27",
});

export async function post({ headers, body }) {
  let event: Stripe.Event;
  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      body,
      headers["stripe-signature"],
      WEBHOOK_SECRET
    );
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      status: 400,
      body: err,
    };
  }

  // Do stuff with the event
}
```

But when it receives an event from Stripe, I get this error:

```
No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing
```

After some research, I found that the body is parsed into JSON by [this function](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/ad09981723b6daa536e68967583aa3a2e1554709/packages/kit/src/core/http/get_body/index.js#L4) before even [SvelteKit hooks](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#hooks) are called, meaning there's no way to directly get the raw body, so I decided my best option was to try to reconstruct the original body:

```
event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
  JSON.stringify(body),
  headers["stripe-signature"],
  WH_SECRET
);
```

I'm not totally certain *why* this doesn't work, since after digging around in [the relevant code in the Stripe library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/lib/Webhooks.js), it seems to handle strings fine. My best guess is that at some point the encoding gets messed up.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, as I'd really like to avoid switching away from SvelteKit, since I've already practically finished my project with it (wasn't a great idea, in retrospect).

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with SvelteKit to comment on getting the raw body, but you will absolutely need the original (not reconstructed) raw body from Stripe's request in order to validate the payload. Might be worth asking (how to avoid the request being parsed) to the [SvelteKit team](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs) directly via the links in their official docs.

Comment: @taintedzodiac I actually did reach out there but didn't get any answers. Also, unless I'm missing something really weird, it appears there is no way to get the raw body without writing a custom adapter and even then it wouldn't work in the development server. Thanks for the confirmation that I'll need to get the actual raw body.

Comment: Beware!, If you have a wrong `WEBHOOK_SECRET`, it gives you the same error

Answer (score 12):

This is how you get the raw body of a request in Svelte Kit:

```
// routeName/+server.js
export async function POST({ request }) {
    const rawBody = await request.text()
    ...
}
```

I also found this while dealing with Stripe and Svelte Kit.

Comment: doesnt work.. we get TypeError: Body is unusable

Answer (score 3):

The payload accepted by `stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payload, signature, secret)` must be of type `string | Buffer`, but the rawBody received in the SvelteKit request is of type `Uint8Array`.

Passing the Uint8Array rawBody or a JSON.stringify'd rawBody as the payload results in the error below from Stripe. Refer: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing

Error
`message: 'No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing'`

We need to convert the rawBody into a `string` or `Buffer` without altering the contents. To achieve this we can use: `Buffer.from(rawBody)`.

So your endpoint would look something like:

```js
...
const stripeWebhookSecret = process.env['STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET'];

export const post: RequestHandler = async (request) => {
  const rawBody = Buffer.from(request.rawBody);
  const signature = request.headers['stripe-signature'];

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      rawBody,
      signature,
      stripeWebhookSecret
    );
...
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this after https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/3384 since `rawBody` is no longer exposed?

Answer (score 2):

I found that the following code worked for me

```
 const body = await request.text();
 const signature = request.headers.get('stripe-signature')|| "";
 const event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
     body,
     signature,
     secret,
 );
```

This did initially give me a `TypeError: Body is unusable` error, but that was because I called `await request.json()` before calling `await request.text()`.