# Verifying Stripe webhook in SvelteKit endpoint: how to get the raw body of a RequestEvent?

Tags: stripe-payments, sveltekit

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66913326/getting-the-raw-body-of-a-request-to-a-sveltekit-endpoint/69277693#69277693), using a more recent version of SvelteKit.

Context: SvelteKit [PR #3384](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/3384) started passing standard `Request` objects to endpoints and removed `rawBody`.

The question linked above has a good answer for how to use `rawBody` to call Stripe's [`constructEvent`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing) to verify the signature of an incoming webhook request, but now that the unmodified body is no longer exposed (as far as I can tell), I'm left wondering how to update my webhook handler.

I've tried calling `constructEvent` with the results of `request.text()`, `request.json()`, `request.arrayBuffer()` (converted to a string), `request.blob().text()`, and the plain `request.body` converted to a string, yet none of them worked. It always throws the same error:

```
No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload.
Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing
```

Comment: Looking at the [Request API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request), you should be able to use `request.body` from the SvelteKit `RequestEvent`. There's an example of this [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/84f6136c567e9adb85005c23d90c02a87ea269d7/packages/adapter-netlify/src/handler.js#L15).

Comment: `request.body: ReadableStream` doesn't match the type for `stripe.webhooks.constructEvent`'s first parameter, which is `string | Buffer`. I tried concatenating the stream into a string and into a Buffer and both resulted in the same error as in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've looked into the node-fetch source code because that's what svelte-kit uses to shim the dev server with and all environments that don't support `Fetch` and there is a method that the standard `Request` class doesn't have and that's [`Request.buffer()`](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/2e1f3a56d1fae91aa3ce01d0ce91b148b00f1b53/src/body.js#L167). With this method I was able to solve that issue. This will only be available in node or serverless environments that don't support fetch natively (nearly every environment except cloudflare).

```
export async function post({ request }: RequestEvent) {
    try {
        const body = await request.buffer();
        const sig = request.headers.get('stripe-signature') as string;
        const e = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body, sig, secret);
        console.log(e.type);
    } catch (_e) {
        console.error(_e);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
charge.succeeded
payment_intent.succeeded
payment_intent.created
```

Comment: Does not work with node in a local environment (node version v18.15.0) `request.buffer is not a function`

Comment: This was pre-v1. Svelte-kit doesn't use `node-fetch` anymore. This should now be possible using the standard `await response.text()` or `new Uint8Array(await response.arrayBuffer())`

Answer (score 3):

Since Stripe accepts strings, I would advise to use `await request.text()` that transforms the body into a raw string. Slightly slower but guaranteed to work in all environments:

```
export async function POST({ request }) {
    try {
        const body = await request.text();
        const signature = request.headers.get('stripe-signature')|| "";
        const event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
            body,
            signature,
            secret,
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Another way would be to do `const body = Buffer.from(await request.arrayBuffer())` but that would work only in Node environments.

Answer (score 2):

`await request.text()` as the body really works!

**But beware!**  If the webhook's `secret` is wrong, it gives exactly the same error

```
No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload.
Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?
```

Comment: Thank you! I lost 20 hours debugging this until I read your beware message.